# how to make javascript random image with hyperlink with array

Tags: javascript, image, random, hyperlink

i want to make random image with link, but i didnt understand. anyone can help me?

this is the javascript in header

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var random_images_array = ['banner/headline/chrome.png','banner/headline/thunderbird.png','banner/headline/vlc.png'];


        function getRandomImage(imgAr, path) {
            path = path || 'images/';

            var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * imgAr.length );
            var img = imgAr[ num ];
            var lnk = imgAr[ num ];

            var imgStr = '<img src="' + path + img + '" alt="" class="img-responsive">';

            document.write(imgStr); document.close();
        }
    </script>
```

this is the javascript in body

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    getRandomImage(random_images_array, 'images/')
                </script>
```

Comment: And the problem you're having is...?

Comment: the link is didnt work

Comment: Where's your image location? `/images/` (absolute) or `images/` (relative)

Comment: Doing this seriously degrades the page loading performance; try to avoid `document.write()` in your scripts and use DOM manipulation instead.

Comment: Have you tried using the web browser debugging tools to see what HTML is getting generated in the page after this code executes?

Comment: @ChrisPietschmann no i didnt try

Comment: And why not? Go check.

Comment: @ChrisPietschmann i already check, and nothing error, but i want to make that image with hyperlink, so i can click on that

Comment: So just wrap the image tag with an a tag...

Comment: @ChrisPietschmann i want to make if the image show google chrome, so the link is going to download google chrome page, if the image show thunderbird or vlc, is going to their download page too, can you help me make that code?

Comment: Your framework is already there with the images, just combine the same with the links.